# Redirecting user to default page after login in ASP.NET Core using Okta

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, openid, okta

I am using Okta for authentication in my ASP.NET Core application. After login, I would like to redirect the user to a different page, but I cannot find where to configure this.

In ConfigureServices:

```
    services.AddAuthentication(sharedOptions =>
            {
                sharedOptions.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                sharedOptions.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                sharedOptions.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddCookie()
            .AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
            {
                options.ClientId = "<clientid>";
                options.ClientSecret = configuration.OktaClientSecret;
                options.Authority = "https://dev-460010-admin.oktapreview.com/oauth2/default";
                options.CallbackPath = "/authorization-code/callback";
                options.ResponseType = "code";
                options.SaveTokens = true;
                options.UseTokenLifetime = false;
                options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
                options.Scope.Add("openid");
                options.Scope.Add("profile");
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    NameClaimType = "name"
                };
            });
```

My login action:

```
    public IActionResult Login()
    {
        if (!HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            return Challenge(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
```

IIRC, what I'm looking for is the equivalent of the `defaultUrl` setting in the FormsAuthentication configuration in ASP.NET.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The new pattern in ASP.NET Core is to specify a post-login destination in the `AuthenticationProperties` when you challenge for login:

```
var properties = new AuthenticationProperties
{
    RedirectUri = "/logged-in"
};

return Challenge(properties, OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
```

It also works the same way during logout.

Full disclosure: I work at Okta and built a lot of our .NET libraries and samples. We need to document this better, I'll make sure we do!

Comment: @MikeCole: Glad to hear that! <3 FYI, we just published a brand new library that makes configuring this even easier: https://github.com/okta/okta-aspnet/
Documentation is still WIP, but should be there soon. Basically turns your code snippet into ~3 lines.