# Open Specific Page With Session Login in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core

Today I create some Login Page with Session to make dynamic menu base on database, the web working fine but if I open specified page like localhost/Student/List before login I throw in to login page and after I'm login the page redirect me into localhost/Home/Index who is the default redirect after login page.
My question is how can i enter the specific address after i login? like using Identity.

I'm Sory I will update my Question.
I'm Using Ajax for my login page, if the result of ajax is true then i will redirect to Home/Index.
That's My Validate Function Login cshtml js

```
function Validate() {
            if ($("#username").val() == null || $("#username").val() == "") {
                $("#message").text("User Name Required!");
            }
            else if ($("#password").val() == null || $("#password").val() == "") {
                $("#message").text("Password Required!");
            }
            else{
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: '@Url.Action("SignIn", "Account")',
                        data: {
                            username : $('#username').val(),
                            password : $('#password').val()
                        },
                        error: function (result) {
                            $("#message").text("There is a Problem, Try Again!");
                        },
                        success: function (result) {
                            console.log(result);
                            if (result.status == true) {
                                window.location.href = '@Url.Action("Index", "Home")';
                            }
                            else {
                                $("#message").text(result.message);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                 }
        }
```

nah, you can see the window.location.href. 
and then my sign in controller

```
public async Task<IActionResult> SignIn(LoginModel model)
        {
            var UserLogin = _dbContext.AspNetUsers.Where(a => a.UserName == model.username).FirstOrDefault();
            if(UserLogin != null)
            {
                if(UserLogin.EmailConfirmed == true)
                {
                    var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.username, model.password, lockoutOnFailure: false, isPersistent: false);
                    if (result.Succeeded)
                    {
                        HttpContext.Session.SetString("email", UserLogin.Email);
                        HttpContext.Session.SetString("username", UserLogin.UserName);
                        HttpContext.Session.SetString("id", UserLogin.Id);
                        HttpContext.Session.SetString("roleId", UserLogin.RolesId);

                        int roleId = Convert.ToInt32(Convert.ToDouble(HttpContext.Session.GetString("roleId")));
                        List<Menus> menus = _dbContext.LinkRolesMenu.Where(a => a.RolesId == roleId).Select(a => a.Menus).ToList();

                        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                        ds = ToDataSet(menus);
                        DataTable table = ds.Tables[0];
                        DataRow[] parentMenus = table.Select("ParentId = 0");

                        var sb = new StringBuilder();
                        string menuString = GenerateUL(parentMenus, table, sb);
                        HttpContext.Session.SetString("menuString", menuString);
                        HttpContext.Session.SetString("menus", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(menus));

                        return Json(new { status = true, message = "Login Successfull!" });

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return Json(new { status = false, message = "Invalid Password!" });
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    return Json(new { status = false, message = "Email Not Confirmed!" });
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return Json(new { status = false, message = "Invalid UserName!" });
            }
        }
```

nah, that's the return return Json(new { status = true, message = "Login Successfull!" });

how can i return that into specific page

Comment: This question might be useful
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51191808/redirecting-user-to-default-page-after-login-in-asp-net-core-using-okta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I open specified page like localhost/Student/List before login I throw in to login page

In my opinion, the only point is that you need to pass the current url (Student/List) as parameter to your login page.Refer to my demo using Custom Authorize Filter

*1.Custom Authorize Filter: judge whether use has already logged in,if not, redirect to login page*

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing;
public class MyAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext filterContext)
    {
        //your judgement to if user has logged in
        if (!filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            //redirect to Account/Login
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
                    new RouteValueDictionary(
                        new
                        {
                            controller = "Account",
                            action = "SignIn",
                            returnUrl = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Path.ToUriComponent()
                        }));
        }

    }
}
```

*2. StudentController:*

```
[MyAuthorizeAttribute]
public class StudentController: Controller
```

*3.AccountController*

```
public IActionResult SignIn(string returnUrl = null)
    {
       // receive returnUrl and pass to View
        ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
        return View();
    }

[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> SignIn(LoginModel model, string returnUrl = null)
    {
        //logic to login

         return Json(new { status = true, message = "Login Successfull!" ,returnUrl = returnUrl });

    }
```

*4.SignIn.cshtml:redirect to `returnUrl` in success callback function*

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '@Url.Action("SignIn", "Account")',
    data: {
        username : $('#username').val(),
        password : $('#password').val(),
        returnUrl: '@ViewBag.ReturnUrl'
    },
    error: function (result) {
        $("#message").text("There is a Problem, Try Again!");
    },
    success: function (result) {
        console.log(result);
        if (result.status == true) {
             window.location.href = result.returnUrl;
        }
        else {
            $("#message").text(result.message);
        }
    }
});
```